# Netbeans shows parsing errors every time I change branches, due to missing lombok generated methods

Tags: java, netbeans, lombok

I am using Netbeans running a Java EE 7 Webapplication.
Every time I switch to a different branch, netbeans shows me randomly some 'files with errors' in the project, saying that these files have parsing errors. I can still 'Clean & Build' but I get an error when deploying.
What helps to resolve these problems is the following:

- Make some random change to the files in question, so I can save the file
- restart netbeans
- delete the complete cache from netbeans

This process is very random and tedious. We are thinking that it has to do with netbeans not finding the right Lombok generated methods. Is there any way to resolve this, permanently?

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the situation quite a lot in the past that specific lombok versions breaks NetBeans support partially or entirely. So be sure to:

1. Try to update lombok to most recent version
2. Try to downgrad lombok some versions
3. Check the lombok bug tracker for [known issues](https://github.com/projectlombok/lombok/issues). They pop up quite fast.
4. Try to upgrade NetBeans to most recent version.

Comment: Currently we are not using maven. It seems like with Maven these problems could be resolved. Some of our devs use intelij and they don't have that problem at all.

Comment: At least it would be easier to change between versions.